# if statement isn't evaluating correctly

Tags: python

I've got Python script:

```
with open('check_door', 'r') as file:
    door = file.readline()

with open('tag_detector_active', 'r') as file2:
    detector = file2.readline()

if door == 'locked' and detector == 'False':
   ...
   ...
```

How is it possible that the if statement doesn't return True when both values `door` and `detector` are set to the right values ?
I checked both values with print function and when I use `if True:` with the rest of the code it runs like a charm. This is so bizzare. Such a simple if statement where nobody can make mistake.

Comment: Probably `door = 'locked\n'`, not `door = 'locked'`. Always log your *actual* values (ie. `print("Door status: %r" % (door,))`) to allow debugging before you escalate to asking questions here. :)

Comment: @sniperd, `print(door)`, unlike `print(repr(door))`, won't necessarily show non-printable characters (could also be trailing whitespace, f/e)..

Comment: Charles, ah, good call.  I didn't think of `repr`

Comment: @TomShanks, I closed this as a duplicate, but if you can [edit] it to contain a [mcve] that lets others reproduce the problem (and it *isn't* actually caused by trailing newlines -- the issue the flagged duplicate will help you solve), @-notify me and I'll re-open it.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what exactly is happening in your code. Otherwise, it's more like a guessing. Put a breakpoint on the line with the condition and check what those two variables actually contain in Watch window.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy @sniperd  Yeah I checked the other topic. `.rstrip()` did the trick. Stupid invisible carriage return.

Comment: Of course, `print(door == 'locked')` would work (at least, in the sense of showing where something is going wrong, albeit not what).

Answer (score 0):

You can print the value of door and check. As you are reading it from the file, it may be possible that some extra space is getting concatenated with the value of door and may be that is why it is not returning True.